# sql procedure to loop through string and input its characters to select

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to create procedure in sql that would be able to produce the following:

```
SET @teststr = '(1, 2, 3)';
select sum(products_storage.product_price)
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 3 as id
     ) i join products_storage
        query_products_in_stock
```

Instead of manually select part, is there a way to loop through teststr string and select each ID from it and have same outcome?

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @teststr)`. But index won't be used. The best way is to parse CSV (if MySQL version allows - use JSON_TABLE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about `find_in_set()`:

```
select sum(products_storage.product_price)
from query_products_in_stock qpin
where find_in_set(qpin.id, replace(replace(replace(@testtr, ', ', ','), '(', ''), ')', '')
```

Of course, this would be simpler if the string were represented as:

```
SET @teststr = '1,2,3';
```

And that begs the question of why you don't specify the query as:

```
select sum(products_storage.product_price)
from query_products_in_stock qpin
where qpin.id like (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: the problem with "where in" is that it won't find duplicate values, the string is actually '1, 2, 3', without the brackets. But with '1, 1, 1' it won't return sum of 3x1 :/

Comment: @qwerty . . . That is not the question that you asked here.  If you want duplicate values to be counted for every occurrence, then the method in your question is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This works with Mysql5.5+

```
SET @teststr = '1, 2, 3';


SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN (select @teststr name from dual) tablename
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
   n;
```